# More than one video driver at the same time

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card

Can I use more than one driver on windows at the same time? I'd like to be able to switch from the offboard video card to the onboard one and vice-versa.

Comment: Out of curiosity... what is the purpose of this?

Comment: Yes, by default it's 1 driver per card. Now, if you're onboard video is disabled by the PCI/AGP/PCIe video card (sometimes the case) then the disabled video card doesn't work.

Comment: You should be able to switch between either of the two in the BIOS settings.

Comment: @KronoS: my main video card stopped working, so i was using the onboard video from the motherboard to try to find out what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just install both of them. When you switch between them, you can just enable and disable monitors in the display properties dialog box.